# Codeigniter username and access level echo

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I output the username and database value "access" in the view? 
It should be on the main page display user name and id of the band, how to implement? The database has a table "Access" at the base of users, you need to get the value and just bring it. Help

Here is my controller and model:

Model:

```
Class User extends CI_Model
{
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('id', 'username', 'password', 'access');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Layout');
    }

    function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
            $this->layout->content('home_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        session_destroy();
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: Im confused, is it a Model or is it a Controller??
`Class User extends CI_Controller`, if its a Model then you should have extended it from CI_Model

Comment: You are using controller code in model and model in controller.Just change your CI_Model to CI_Controller and vice versa.To get username or anything anywhere in your project use Codeigniter Sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Users should be a Model and Home should be a Controller.

when you get the user name from the table, make a `$this->session->set_userdata('username', $username)` where $username is the query result.

There is another problem. CI does not use `$_SESSION` so `session_destroy()` will not work, use
`$this->session->sess_destroy()` instead.